# Segmentation fault: core dumped during execution of multi-threaded program

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, mutex, semaphore

I have realized that my code was too lengthy and rather hard to read.

Can you check over the way I pass in the arguments and constructing the arguments in the main body? 
Essentially, provided that I have correct implementation of "produce" and "consume" functions, I want to pass in a shared circular queue and semaphores and mutexes to each produce/consume threads.

```
typedef struct circularQueue
{
    int *items;
    int *head;
    int *tail;
    int numProduced;
    int numConsumed;
} circularQueue;

typedef struct threadArg
{
    int id;
    circularQueue *queue;
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
    sem_t *spaces;
    sem_t *itemAvail;
    int numItems;
    int bufferSize;
    int numProducer;
    int numConsumer;
} threadArg;

pthread_t *producerThd;
pthread_t *consumerThd;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    // In fo to pass to thread arg
    circularQueue *myQueue;
    pthread_mutex_t useSharedMem;
    sem_t spaces;
    sem_t itemAvail;
    int numItems;
    int bufferSize;
    int numProducer;
    int numConsumer;

    int i, j, k, l;

    if(argc != 5)
    {
        printf("Enter in 4 arguments - N B P C\n");
        return -1;
    }
    numItems = atoi(argv[1]);
    bufferSize = atoi(argv[2]);
    numProducer = atoi(argv[3]);
    numConsumer = atoi(argv[4]);

    if(numItems == 0 || bufferSize == 0 || numProducer == 0 || numConsumer == 0)
    {
        printf("Parameters should not be 0\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize list of threads
    producerThd = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numProducer);
    consumerThd = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numConsumer);

    // Initialize semaphores
    sem_init(&spaces, 0, bufferSize);
    sem_init(&itemAvail, 0, 0);

    // Initialize mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&useSharedMem, NULL);

    // Initialzie thread attributes
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);


    // Initialize queue

    myQueue = (circularQueue*)malloc(sizeof(circularQueue));
    myQueue->items = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*bufferSize);
    myQueue->head = myQueue->items;
    myQueue->tail = myQueue->items;
    myQueue->numProduced = 0;
    myQueue->numConsumed = 0;



    // thread arguments
    for(i = 0; i < numProducer; i++)
    {
        // Initialize thraed args
        threadArg *args = (threadArg*)malloc(sizeof(threadArg));
        args->queue = (circularQueue*)malloc(sizeof(circularQueue));
        args->mutex = &useSharedMem;
        args->spaces = &spaces;
        args->itemAvail = &itemAvail;
        args->numItems = numItems;
        args->bufferSize = bufferSize;
        args->numProducer = numProducer;
        args->numConsumer = numConsumer;
        args->id = i;
        pthread_t thisThread = *(producerThd + i);
        pthread_create(&thisThread, &attr, produce, args);
    }

    for(j = 0; j < numConsumer; j++)
    {
        // Initialize thraed args
        threadArg *args = (threadArg*)malloc(sizeof(threadArg));
        args->queue = (circularQueue*)malloc(sizeof(circularQueue));
        args->mutex = &useSharedMem;
        args->spaces = &spaces;
        args->itemAvail = &itemAvail;
        args->numItems = numItems;
        args->bufferSize = bufferSize;
        args->numProducer = numProducer;
        args->numConsumer = numConsumer;
        args->id = j;
        pthread_t thisThread = *(consumerThd + i);
        pthread_create(&thisThread, &attr, consume, args);
    }

    for(k = 0; k < numProducer; k++)
    {
        pthread_join(*(producerThd+k), NULL);
    }

    printf("Finished waiting for producers\n");


    for(l = 0; l < numConsumer; l++)
    {
        pthread_join(*(consumerThd+l), NULL);
    }
    printf("Finished waiting for consumers\n");


    free(producerThd);
    free(consumerThd);
    free(myQueue->items);
    free(myQueue);
    sem_destroy(&spaces);
    sem_destroy(&itemAvail);

    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You understand that multithreaded programs do not have an order to execute code from every thread, thus the crash might be happening in any of the threads so you can't say that it's happening here or there. Also, undefined behavior tends to be like that too, it might occur or not depending on things like the data the program is dealing with so it's also not possible to predict when or where will this kind of error occur.

Comment: This is a lot of code, if you can just use [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) and the problem will be easier to find.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that each thread has its own mutex, so they don't actually lock each other out like you're expecting them to. (And you called pthread_mutex_init once for both mutexes which is probably undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple sources of undefined behavior in your code, you are either compiling without enabling compilation warnings, or what I consider worst you ignore them.

1. You have the wrong `printf()` specifier in

   ```
   printf("cid %d found this item %d as valid item %d\n", myArgs->id, thisItem, validItem);
   ```

   because `validItem` is a `double`, so the last specifier should be `%f`.
2. Your thread functions never return a value, but you declare them to return `void *` which is the signature required for such functions.
3. You are freeing and dereferencing `myQueue` in the `main()` function but you have not initialized it because that code is commented.

Your code is also too hard to read because you have no consistent style and you mix declarations with statements, which make everything very confusing, e.g. determining the scope of a variable is very difficult.

Fixing the code will not only help others read it, but will also help you fix it and find issues quickly.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your answer. I did realize that the code is rather lengthy. I will edit the question so that it asks specific questions regarding my code